# Function that returns, dynamically, how much code has been executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do a 'loading screen' that reflects exactly what percentage of my code has executed.
I know that is how: distributing 'flags' by the code, and these flags would assume the value of the percentages. This in conexto static. What I would populate my code with 'flags', and worse, in a static manner. Is there any way to know 'how much' of my code has been processed?

Comment: won't this result in a delay/affect the execution? I mean, checking what has executed will slow down the script and it defies the purpose of showing the percentage executed, doesn't it?

Comment: I think it'd be more worthwhile to devote your time to improving the efficiency of the code so that you don't have to entertain the user while it's running.

Comment: Man, I deal with requests 'ajax' and this process itself has no way to be improved. then it is even fair to the user whether the request is being processed it yet. this, of course, for my system. :)

Comment: Loading screen shouldn't be by percentage of lines-of-code executed, it should be by *portion of time*. Which means, you need to know roughly how long each section of your code takes. E.g., some loops may only be 4 lines of code, but take 90% of the time. Or your AJAX request for 2MB of XML is much longer than the request for a true/false.

Answer (score 3):

No, not in javascript.  And it wouldn't make sense to do it line-by-line anyways.  Some lines of code (ex. ajax calls, alerts) can take far longer than others to complete.

I would recommend using flags.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [JSCoverage](http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/demo.html). It's a little old, but it looks like it might give you an idea of how to go about doing something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, unless it's instrumented in some way.